# How to combine two regex(pattern) value int one

Tags: shell

Below is the input

```
This is shard24 and date 20170801
This is shard24 and date 20170801
This is shard25 and date 20180101

file | sed -e 's/.*\(2018[0-9]*\).*/\1/p' -e 's/.*\(shard[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

The above command give me value as

```
shard24
20170801
shard24
20170801
shard25
20180101
```

Expected output

```
shard2420170801
shard2420170801
shard2520180101
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` regular expresisons

```
sed -e 's/.*\(shard[0-9]*\).*\(201[0-9]\+\).*/\1\2/'
```

or with  extended regular expressions

```
sed -re 's/.*(shard[0-9]*).*(201[0-9]+).*/\1\2/'
```

which looks a bit more clear.

Comment: echo "record1: shard10 test 201801 
record2:shard15 lets see 201801" | sed -e 's/.*\(shard[0-9]*\).*\(201[0-9]\+\).*/\1\2/'

record1: shard10 test 201801 

record2:shard15 lets see 201801

expected output: (2 Row)

shard10201801
shard15201801

Comment: You mixed up sed regexp with extended regexp. This proposed solution works `echo -e "record1: shard10 test 201801\nrecord2:shard15 lets see 201801" | sed -re 's/.*(shard[0-9]*).*(201[0-9]+).*/\1\2/'`